# What is the maximum number of non-overlapping circles that can be placed inside an ellipse?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, packing-problem

Consider a standard ellipse of equation:
$$\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

and let the circle be given a radius $r$. Is there some algorithm useful to calculate it?

Comment: If I am not wrong, if you differ the centers of the circles only by $dx$, then you may fit infinite circles inside one ellipse.

Comment: @GaurangTandon: sorry: the circles must be not overlapping

Comment: [Circle packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle) is notoriously difficult.There is probably no generalizable pattern to the various arrangements. I don't know if anyone has tried packing circles inside an ellipse before.

Comment: You probably mean of a given radius, otherwise the number is unbounded.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Hi sorry by mistake I had deleted that part of the question of the OP while cleaning it up. I have added it now. The OP had mentioned given a circle of radius $r$. [Revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2647506/revisions) Thank you for your cooperation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't known for an ellipse, because in the special case where $a=b,$ it is still unknown what optimal circle packings there are for circles . . .

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle